# reconfigure repository settings from github to bitbucket in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git

I'm making my own project with github in eclipse.

Since github does not provide free private repository, I made a decision to import my project from github to bitbucket.

Successfully, I imported github to bitbucket repository, but now it's time to reconfigure my project setting in eclipse in order to commit in bitbucket from now on.

How can I reconfigure the remote repository of my project 'in eclipse'?

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse IDE:

- Window > Show View (alt+Shift+q q), select "Git repositories"
- Browse your repository to show the "remotes"
- right-click on your remote repository reference and you should see something like "Configure" that allows changing URL.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution.

After importing the project from github to bitbucket, you should reconfigure in your local machine to commit to new repository.

So,

1.Find `/your git repository/.git/config` file.

2.Modify following,

```
[remote "origin"]
      url = ... modify your old url to new url here!
...
```

That's it.

Comment: Better use the specified "git remote set-url" command: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote